# Magnetic mirror and Van Allen's belt

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields

Qualitatively, I understand that Van Allen's radiation belt is formed from the magnetic trap phenomenon. The particles are trapped in a region of variable magnetic field, and the force exerted on the charges, when they approach the ends of the region, is such that they reverse their direction and return to the confined area. This is the "mirroring" that gives the phenomenon its name, and occurs for charges with speeds and angular displacements below a convenient limit.

This "trapping" of charged particles, strictly speaking, the phenomenon of returning to the confinement area, causes a high-density region of energetic particles to be generated in space, which is Van Allen's radiation belt. I understand that the magnetic bottle model is appropriate to scheme how the earth traps the charged particles from the sun, and we will have a formatting in which the particles will spiral between the two ends.

Well, qualitatively it's not very difficult to understand at first. But I'm having some difficulties in mathematically expressing this belt formation. Of course, I must use equations of electromagnetism, but this transition is confusing me. Particularly, how can I mathematically describe, from the properties of magnetic mirroring, the formation of van Alllen's belt, with all its properties, from this "spiraling" of particles?

Of course, as it is a region of variable magnetic induction over time, using the differential form of Faraday's Law:

$\nabla \times \mathbf E = -\frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t}$

We easily conclude that the electric field in this region is not conservative. I believe that, perhaps, it is this fact that makes the quantitative description difficult.

Anyway, if anyone can point me to some directions on how to use the equations of electromagnetism in this situation, I'll be grateful.